# Counting consecutive items within SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Got a problem with a query I'm trying to write. I have a table that lists people that have been sent an email. There is a bit column named Active which is set to true if they have responded. But I need to count the number of consecutive emails the person has been inactive since either their first email or last active email.

For example, this basic table shows one person has been sent 9 emails. They have been active within two of the emails (3 & 5). So their inactive count would be 4 as we are counting from email number 6 onwards.

```
PersonID(int)    EmailID(int)    EmailDate(datetime)    Active(bit)
1                1               2009-07-18 19:56:20    0
1                2               2009-08-18 19:56:20    0
1                3               2009-09-18 19:56:20    1
1                4               2009-10-18 19:56:20    0
1                5               2009-11-18 19:56:20    1
1                6               2009-12-18 19:56:20    0
1                7               2010-01-18 19:56:20    0
1                8               2010-02-18 19:56:20    0
1                9               2010-03-18 19:56:20    0
```

Any pointers or help would be great.

Regards
Greg

Comment: My 2c - the Active column should be called HasResponded to actually indicate the action.

Comment: Is your sample data an accurate description of the problem?  What I mean is are the EmailIDs always *guaranteed* to be consecutive (without breaks in the numbering) within each PersonID value?

Comment: There are dates associated to the emails.  Think I'll edit the post to reflect this.

Comment: My question about the EmailIDs still stands even with the dates — your problem is easier if the IDs are consecutive.

Comment: Hi Larry, there is no guarantee that the EmailID will be sequential.  But the EmailDate will be (just added in as it should be there).

Comment: Both Answers work well and return the results I need.  Thank you Larry and KM.  I have checked Larry's as the answer as it is the quicker performing query of the two (only by 1 second querying over 2 million records).  Thanks all!

Comment: your selected answer will not work if an all e-mails are inactive for an employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first cut:

```
SELECT PersonID, COUNT(*) FROM Table T1
WHERE Active = 0 AND EmailDate > 
   (SELECT MAX(EMailDate) FROM Table T2 
       WHERE T2.PersonID = T1.PersonID AND Active = 1)
GROUP BY PersonID
```

Note that this solution requires that each person answers at least one email.  If you want to include people who were inactive from the very first email that was sent to them you need to wrap that (MAX(EmailDate)) term inside some kind of IFNULL() returning a date before the start date of the system for NULLs.

Also, as KM points out below, if someone is not currently inactive (they answered the most recent email) they will not be in the result set.  I think that probably meets your needs but, if not, let me know.

Comment: doesn't work if there is more than one employee in the table.

Comment: Hi Larry, thanks for this, it seems to be returning good results on my full dataset.  Thank you!!

Comment: @KM: Why not?  Inner SELECT is correlated to outer PersonID.

Comment: @Greg: A pleasure to be of assistance.

Comment: try it on my data, I get 1 row back

Comment: What happens if the longest sequence of inactives starts at one?

Comment: Thanks @KM: I forgot to add to my original post that my solution requires each person to respond to at least one email.  In addition, your data exposes another condition, that it won't report people who are not currently inactive (although I think the second case probably matches what the OP wants to see).  I will update.

Comment: @Thomas, that is why my results are differ than this one, my EmployeeID=2 has all rows inactive, my query returns it, but this one doesn't

Comment: @KM I don't mean all rows inactive. Using the OP example, suppose rows 1-4 are inactive and that 5 and 7 (and even 9) are active. There are active values but longest sequence is from 1-4.

Comment: @Larry Lustig, if you run you query against my data you do not find EmployeeID=2 in the result set, but it shoul dhave a count of 6, which has not been active for any e-mails. I would think this would error would not meet the needs since they are looking at counting these rows.

Comment: @KM, yes that's true.  I edited the answer some time ago to suggest the solution in the event that this is a problem.

Comment: @Thomas: The OP is not asking for the longest sequence of inactivity, but rather the current sequence of inactivity.

Comment: Just seen all the latest updates to this.  Thanks all for the responses.  I have got the query up and running in my test system and with a few tweaks (mentioned above) and it's running great.  For my first post on this site, I'm very impressed with all the quality and speed in feedback!

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Emails table (PersonID int, EmailID int,  Active bit)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 1,1,0)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 1,2,0)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 1,3,1)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 1,4,0)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 1,5,1)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 1,6,0)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 1,7,0)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 1,8,0)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 1,9,0)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 2,1,0)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 2,2,0)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 2,3,0)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 2,4,0)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 2,5,0)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 2,6,0)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 3,1,1)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 3,2,1)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 3,3,1)
INSERT @Emails VALUES ( 3,4,1)
SET NOCOUNT OFF


SELECT
    e.PersonID,COUNT(e.EmailID) AS CountInactive
    FROM @Emails e
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
                             PersonID,MAX(EmailID) AS LastActive
                             FROM @Emails
                             WHERE Active=1
                             GROUP BY PersonID
                        ) dt ON e.PersonID=dt.PersonID
    WHERE e.EmailID>ISNULL(dt.LastActive,0)
    GROUP BY e.PersonID
```

OUTPUT:

```
PersonID    CountInactive
----------- -------------
1           4
2           6

(2 row(s) affected)
```

**EDIT** after OP's edit, same output as above:

```
SELECT
    e.PersonID,COUNT(e.EmailID) AS CountInactive
    FROM @Emails e
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
                             PersonID,MAX(EmailDate) AS LastActive
                             FROM @Emails
                             WHERE Active=1
                             GROUP BY PersonID
                        ) dt ON e.PersonID=dt.PersonID
    WHERE (e.EmailDate>ISNULL(dt.LastActive,0)) OR dt.PersonID IS NULL
    GROUP BY e.PersonID
```

Answer (score 0):

A version of @Larry-Lustig's answer that uses COALESCE to return counts for users with no emails:

```
SELECT PersonID, COUNT(*) FROM Table T1
WHERE Active = 0 AND EmailDate > 
   COALESCE (
       (SELECT MAX(EMailDate) FROM Table T2 
           WHERE T2.PersonID = T1.PersonID AND T2.Active = 1),
       DATEFROMPARTS(1900,1,1))
GROUP BY PersonID
```